# Detected potentially harmful notification post rate

Tags: xcode, macos

When running my app in Xcode I sometimes get the following log in my debug area:

```
Detected potentially harmful notification post rate ...
```

What is that?

I'm running Xcode 9.1 and macOS High Sierra 10.13.1

Output from console prior to warning

```
    (null selector)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000001110
2018-05-12 07:40:41.194500+0200 Omnia[76129:3921267] Detected potentially harmful notification post rate of 1211.73
```

Comment: This could be anything from a notification event (eg. `postNotification`) to a mouse event (eg. `mouseDragged`), what is the rate it's showing?

Comment: Detected potentially harmful notification post rate of 1224.26 notifications per second. I am not dragging the mouse. The warning comes as soon as I start my app. I am not posting any notifications in my code.

Comment: Usually you'll find the cause of the warning in Console right before that message, so maybe see if there's anything indicating an error perhaps. It's can be very difficult to pinpoint, as it will do this at times even when there's a problem with `NSUserDefaults` or a dirty cache. Some people have reported the problem goes away after a reboot, so that might be worth a shot. It could even be a bug with the OS, I presume you are using 10.13.1 - that seems to be where it's popping up.

Comment: Whatever that error is I'm guessing it's the culprit; I suppose anything else throwing an error right in that area of the log as well could be responsible. Any errors with "Omnia" in that vicinity?

Comment: (null selector)]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000001110
2018-05-12 07:40:41.194500+0200 Omnia[76129:3921267] Detected potentially harmful notification post rate of 1211.73. The null selector is most probably the culprit

Comment: Yep, it's obviously something in relation to "selector", so maybe search on that or look in IB at the connections inspector and see if there's anything with a `⚠︎` next to it and you'll probably find it.

Comment: I found the bug. It was the null selector that was causing it. Once I removed it, the warning disappeared. Thanks I'L'I